# How to get a better understanding and knowledge of metaphors

Tags: discussion

I want to incorporate less formal, technical, and literal terms into my vocabulary to help articulate some theoretical points in any scenario. I heard someone say

> you'd catch more flies with honey than vinegar.

I thought that was great and want to learn more of these. Any direct readings to help understand common ones like these?

Comment: I'd call that an "aphorism" (not a "metaphor"), so you might want to look up lists of English aphorisms. (It might also be called an "adage", "proverb", etc., although slight distinctions exist among all of those terms.)

Answer (score 2):

- [The Great Book of American Idioms {link via Amazon}](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/169965431X) contains a good selection, with interpretations.
- The Oxford Dictionary of Idioms.
- The Penguin Dictionary of Idioms.
- The Macmillan Dictionary Of English Colloquial Idioms